# Can I pay for my Netflix subscription using iTunes credit?

Tags: appletv, itunes-store, billing, netflix

Now that you can sign up for Netflix with your Apple ID and use that for billing, does that allow you to get it billed to your iTunes Credit rather than credit card?

Comment: News article related to this story: http://www.pcworld.com/article/251500/netflix_improves_with_new_apple_tv.html

Comment: Similar question on a forum: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1345515

Comment: I don't know for certain if this is also how it works for Netflix, but it definitely goes towards any store credit you have for Hulu+.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Bloomberg article](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2012-03-07/netflix-expands-apple-tv-alliance-with-itunes.html):

> Netflix Inc. (NFLX) is deepening its ties with Apple Inc. (AAPL) by
>   **allowing owners of Apple TV set-top boxes to sign up for the
>   video-streaming service directly and pay through their iTunes
>   accounts.**

More details and support links can be found on Netflix's [iTunes billing page](http://support.netflix.com/en/netflix-itunes-billing-apple-tv).

Finally, according to the current US [iTunes terms and conditions](http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html):

> When making purchases, content credits are used first, followed by
>   Gift Certificate, iTunes Card, or Allowance Account credits; your
>   credit card or PayPal account is then charged for any remaining
>   balance.

While the current T&C doesn't directly mention the Netflix subscription situation., the iTunes Card ("credit") comes before the credit card or PayPal account. However, since Apple also has your credit card information, as this [Fast Company article](http://www.fastcompany.com/1824085/netflix-deal-reveals-apples-secret-sauce-itunes-pay-channel) notes, your credit card might actually be used to pay for your Netflix subscription instead of the iTunes credits.